# InvalidParameterError: The 'bootstrap' parameter of RandomForestClassifier

Tags: streamlit

I am getting  the following error:

InvalidParameterError: The 'bootstrap' parameter of RandomForestClassifier must be an instance of 'bool', an instance of 'numpy.bool_' or an instance of 'int'. Got 'True' instead.

I am running the following code:

```
    if classifier == 'Random Forest':
        st.sidebar.subheader ("Model Hyperparameters") 
        n_estimators= st.sidebar.number_input ("The Number of trees in the forst",100,5000,step = 10, key = 'n_estimators' )
        max_depth   = st.sidebar.number_input ("The maxuim depth of the tree", 1,20, step=1, key ='max_depth')
        bootstrap =st.sidebar.radio ("Booststrap samples when building tree", ('True', 'False'), key = 'bootstrap')
        metrics = st.sidebar.multiselect("What meterices to plot?", ("Confusion Matrix Display","Roc Curve Display", "Precision-Recal Curve"))

        if st.sidebar.button("Classify", key ='classify'):
            st.subheader("Random Forest")
            model =RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=n_estimators, max_depth=max_depth, bootstrap= bootstrap, n_jobs =-1)
            model.fit (x_train, y_train)
            
            accuracy = model.score(x_test,y_test)
            y_pred =model.predict(x_test)
            
            st.write ("Accuracy  :", accuracy.round(2))
            st.write("Precision :", precision_score (y_test, y_pred, labels=class_names).round (2))
            st.write("Recall ", recall_score(y_test, y_pred,labels=class_names).round(2))
            plot_metrics(metrics)       

    if classifier == 'Random Forest':
        st.sidebar.subheader ("Model Hyperparameters") 
        n_estimators= st.sidebar.number_input ("The Number of trees in the forst",100,5000,step = 10, key = 'n_estimators' )
        max_depth   = st.sidebar.number_input ("The maxuim depth of the tree", 1,20, step=1, key ='max_depth')
        bootstrap =st.sidebar.radio ("Booststrap samples when building tree", ('True', 'False'), key = 'bootstrap')
        metrics = st.sidebar.multiselect("What meterices to plot?", ("Confusion Matrix Display","Roc Curve Display", "Precision-Recal Curve"))

        if st.sidebar.button("Classify", key ='classify'):
            st.subheader("Random Forest")
            model =RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=n_estimators, max_depth=max_depth, bootstrap= bootstrap, n_jobs =-1)
            model.fit (x_train, y_train)
            
            accuracy = model.score(x_test,y_test)
            y_pred =model.predict(x_test)
            
            st.write ("Accuracy  :", accuracy.round(2))
            st.write("Precision :", precision_score (y_test, y_pred, labels=class_names).round (2))
            st.write("Recall ", recall_score(y_test, y_pred,labels=class_names).round(2))
            plot_metrics(metrics)
```